# Failure to install cairo: missing symbol _cairo_region_create_rectangles

Tags: haskell, cairo

I am trying to install the cairo backend for the Chart package.  I first installed GTK and cairo as per the instructions [here (Chart instructions)](https://github.com/timbod7/haskell-chart/wiki) and [here (GTK/cairo)](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Gtk2Hs/Installation) and have the newest versions as of this post: `cairo-0.12.5.3` and `gtk-0.12.5.7`.

However, when trying to use cairo, I run into a wall with the following step.

```
> cabal install chart-cairo
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring Chart-cairo-1.2.2...
Building Chart-cairo-1.2.2...
Preprocessing library Chart-cairo-1.2.2...
[1 of 1] Compiling Graphics.Rendering.Chart.Backend.Cairo ( Graphics\Rendering\Chart\Backend\Cairo.hs, dist\build\Graphics\Rendering\Chart\Backend\Cairo.o )
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Loading package array-0.4.0.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package deepseq-1.3.0.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package bytestring-0.10.0.2 ... linking ... done.
Loading package transformers-0.3.0.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package mtl-2.1.2 ... linking ... done.
Loading package utf8-string-0.3.7 ... linking ... done.
Loading package cairo-0.12.5.3 ... linking ... ghc.exe: C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\cabal\i386-windows-ghc-7.6.3\cairo-0.12.5.3\libHScairo-0.12.5.3.a: unknown symbol `_cairo_region_create_rectangles'*
ghc.exe: unable to load package `cairo-0.12.5.3'
Failed to install Chart-cairo-1.2.2
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
Chart-cairo-1.2.2 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

Other cairo programs fail as well.  The `Drawing.hs` file installed with it, for example, fails with:

```
Loading package cairo-0.12.5.3 ... linking ... <interactive>: C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\cabal\i386-windows-ghc-7.6.3\cairo-0.12.5.3\libHScairo-0.12.5.3.a: unknown symbol `_cairo_region_create_rectangles'
ghc.exe: unable to load package `cairo-0.12.5.3'
```

The symbol is missing from the .a file.  `nm` lists it as `u` (undefined).

There's an open [bug](http://trac.haskell.org/gtk2hs/ticket/1211) on this, but it hasn't been touched in three years.  (The bug has a comment that suggests the problem is related to Template Haskell, but I am not doing anything with TH.)

Do I need a newer or older version of the cairo library or something?  Where is the above function defined and why isn't it in the library?  Any suggestions of how to address this?

Thanks!

**EDIT**
I finally determined that Graphviz and Gnuplot were higher in %PATH% than than the GTK bundle and both have their own `cairo.dll`.  Hence, the wrong one was getting picked up by the runtime linker.  After removing those path elements and attempting a reinstall of all of cairo and GTK.  I run into a new problem:

```
`libHSgtk-0.12.5.7.a: unknown symbol `__imp___fmode'`.
```

I tried a clean install of the Haskell gtk and cairo packages (the whole process) and ensured all the dlls loaded this time and verified the GTK directory with Process Explorer. Sadly, I don't have any more time to work on this and must abandon attempting to get cairo working with Haskell on Windows. Maybe I'll try it again someday in the future.

Comment: cairo 0.12 is very very old..., try maybe with [this toolkit](http://gladewin32.sourceforge.net/) reference on cairo site:

Comment: That is the version number of the Haskell binding, not of cairo itself.

Comment: @Tim It seems the installed `cairo` package is somehow broken. Try to unregister it (`ghc-pkg unregister cairo`) and reinstall it with cabal; that might give us more clues or, with luck, even solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Cairo Commit logs](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/cairo/commit/?id=1cca5a1348d071a3c8e2ba9d3ba0d9670b9564f4), the leading `underscore`of that function has been removed in `cairo-`**1.9.2**. Consider using a version prior to it if the caller is on Haskel side (which seems not according to our comments) or a version newer if the exception is thrown inside gtk package.

Comment: That can't be the problem. I currently use the Cairo Haskell bindings (and the Chart library) without problems with cairo 1.12.16. Furthermore, the Cairo bindings are actively maintained (the [latest version](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cairo-0.12.5.3) was published in 2014/03/01). Something this obvious wouldn't have been left unfixed since 2009.

Comment: in cairo 1.12.16, the function is without leading underscore, so, there's a call not updated somewhere, but i've no knowledge on Haskell. `libHScairo-0.12.5.3.a` seems to be the caller...

Comment: If that was so then everyone else who uses the bindings would have been affected by this issue, which is not the case. Symbols in general do not match exactly the names of the functions they originated from.

Comment: @Tim: depending of you working env, check if no other cairo developpement package could interfer with your Haskell stuff..., I couldn't say more

Comment: @Tim: theres a choice on [that page](http://projects.haskell.org/gtk2hs/). Have you choose gtk2 or 3? Or maybe you've not downloaded from there (Sorry I know nothing about Haskell). try gtk+3 if not the case.

Comment: @Tim: it seems a complete build system your Haskell stuffs. What I understand so far, is that one of your library is built with Cairo headers older than 1.9.2. Check where cairo.h is on your system and find nearby cairo-version.h, you'll maybe find something.

Comment: That is possible (Tim might have downloaded a very old GTK package for Windows). The Cairo version can be checked with `pkg-config cairo --modversion`.

Comment: @duplode `pkg-config cairo --modversion` reported `1.10.2`.

Comment: I downloaded the newest all-in-one bundle of GTK "gtk+-bundle_2.24.10-20120208_win32.zip" listed at <www.gtk.org/download/win32.php>. The Haskell binding requires a 2.x version of GTK instead of the 3.x.

Comment: It's not solved yet.  I have to step back and think about this some more (try and figure out what's interfering).

Comment: I am accepting this answer since it was on the right track (an older `cairo.dll` was getting picked up by the Haskell runtime). Thanks to everyone for their help!